# How is Procrustes Distance Defined?

Tags: geometry, analysis, statistics, metric-spaces, procrustes-problem

How is Procrustes Distance defined between two given datasets?
Assume that the datasets each of them having "k" points in "n" dimensions.

I couldn't find a proper source anywhere with a mathematical expression. I found some leads, but they are in research papers, etc.

In wikipedia there is a statement which says - "minimum sum of squared distances between corresponding landmarks" but is pointwise or corresponding points?, I'm not sure. Please help. Thanks

Comment: How is Procrustes Distance defined between two given datasets? 
Assume that the datasets each of them having "k" points in "n" dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procrustes Distance is defined as follows:

As you have already mentioned, assume that we have two datasets **M** and **N** of size [k x n], where k = number of datapoints, and n = no. of dimensions.

Procrustes method "transforms" **M** and **N** into **A** and **B** respectively.

And the method of the above transformation is governed (by translate, rotate and scaling rules) in order to minimise the Procrustes Distance between **A** and **B**.

$$ Procrustes\_distance(A, B) = \sqrt{\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^k(x^{A}_{ij} - x^{B}_{ij})^{2}} $$

In other words, consider $X = A - B$;
Then,
$$ Procrustes\_distance(A,B)=\operatorname{trace}\left(X^{T} X\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Comment: There is a connection with Frobenius norm.